# How is the sample mean an unbiased estimator of the population mean via deeplearningbook.org?

Tags: expected-value, bias, unbiased-estimator

So I know that the sample mean is a unbiased estimator of the population mean.  Just wondering how the author gets from 5.33 to 5.34 in the below.

How do you get from $\mathbb{E}[\mu_m]$ to just $\mu$ not $\hat{\mu}$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We are told that $x^{(i)} \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ from equation $5.29$.

> $$p(x^{(i)}; \mu, \sigma^2) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left( -\frac12 \frac{(x^{(i)}-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\tag{5.29}$$

Hence $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\mu.$

Note that $\mu_m$ is a statistics, not a parameter, where $\mu_m = \frac1m \sum_{i=1}^mx^{(i)}$.

Comment: I don't get how we know the true $\mu$ if all we have access to is the sample data.  In 5.33, we have $E[x^i]$ which is the expected value of our sample xi.  That should equal the sample mean, not the population mean.  Not sure how he is able to plug the population mean into 5.34.

Comment: You do not need to know the value of $\mu$ in order to write down notation $\mu$.  If you are told that $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then $E[X]=\mu$. The sample mean $\mu_m$ is an approximation of $\mu$. The proof has illustrated that $E[\mu_m]=\mu$ using the linearity of expected value.

Answer (score 1):

It’s an assumption of his model.

Look at the previous page, Eq 5.29. He assumes that $x^{(i)}\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, i.i.d. Gaussian. By definition, then $E[x^{(i)}]=\mu$.